# knockoutMvc - HelloWorld Tutorial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout-mvc

I am attempting a tutorial on KnockoutMVC (see below) I have downloaded .nuget extension and made reference to it in my project...so....

http://knockoutmvc.com/HelloWorld

Using the above tutorial in VS. When I add the 'model' I am getting an error with [computed] - the type or namespace name 'computedAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
 public class HelloWorldModel
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }

  [Computed]
  public string FullName
  {
    get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am missing. Is there another download?
Thanks

EDIT:
Also the same error for 'ActionResult' & 'BaseController' in the controller:

```
    public class HelloWorldController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        InitializeViewBag("Hello world");
        return View(new HelloWorldModel
        {
            FirstName = "Steve",
            LastName = "Sanderson"
        });
    }
}
```

dto the NuGet.Core would resolve this?

Comment: The tutorial is not very good as it doesn't mention the base classes used in the demos as well as it is missing some lines of code. The BaseController class is defined in the downloads. For the examples used on the site, you can ommit them and inherit your controller classes directly from KnockoutController instead. Another hint: If working with MVC 4, have a look at BundleConfig to define the neccessary script imports and have them loaded in _layout.[vb|cs]html.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the package installed? If not you should open the package manager console and type
Install-Package kMVC

Then in the model put: using DelegateDecompiler;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks SLin. I was having the same problem. Your answer fixed it for me.

The Hello World Tutorial also forgets to mention you need to reference knockout-2.2.0.js and knockout.mapping-latest.js at the top of the view.

"Do you have the package installed? If not you should open the package manager console and type Install-Package kMVC

Then in the model put: using DelegateDecompiler;"

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues.  This package looks promising but I am not actually seeing anything run from the sample code after using NuGet to restore any missing packages/dependencies.  For example, when I run this sample, HelloWorld, I can enter a first and last name in the checkbox but I don't see those values update in the UI.  It remains unchanged/blank.  Anyone have any ideas why?  I am running the code provided from KnockoutMVC's site: https://github.com/AndreyAkinshin/knockout-mvc